MAUI .Net8 iOS DidReceiveRemoteNotification never invoked
I'm writing a .Net8 MAUI App targeting iOS. The application should be able to received remote APNS notifications. This works fine while the application is in foreground. The method WillPresentNotification is then invoked and the notification processed.
What I can't get to work is processing notifications while in background, without the user clicking on the notification. In other words, I'd like my application to process the notification payload, even if the user doesn't click on the notification.
I understand that the method DidReceiveRemoteNotification should be invoked (... according to other articles I've found, like this one. The difference is that I'm using .Net8 instead of .Net7. I've tried to modify my csproj file as mentioned in that article, not working for me.
The C# code of the methods I'm trying to trigger looks like this:
[Export("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")]
public void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary notification, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            //code to write the notification to the DB and display the local notification

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }

[Foundation.Export("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:")]
public void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIKit.UIApplication application, Foundation.NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);

        }

Interestingly enough, this method is not defined in UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate or in the MauiUIApplicationDelegate interfaces, so I can't actually override it.
Has anybody managed to handle notifications while in background on iOS using MAUI and .Net8?

this method is not defined in UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate or in the MauiUIApplicationDelegate interfaces, so I can't actually override it. Have you tried put these methods just in AppDelegate?

@LiqunShen-MSFT, yes, I tried that (... I've tried a ton of things). If you happen to be able to point me to a sample .Net8 MAUI app where DidReceiveRemoteNotification is actually invoked when a notification is received and the app is backgrounded, that would be much appreciated.

Can your app receive notification in Background? Is DidReceiveRemoteNotification invoked?

I've set the ability to receive notifications in background in Inof.plist. The problem is that when the app is in background, DidReceiveRemoteNotification is never invoked, but my expectation would be for the method to be invoked for both silent notifications or "alert" type notifications. When the app is in foreground, notifications are received by the WillPresentNotification() method, which works fine.

Do you also use Plugin.Firebase?  Here are many possibilities that may cause this issue,  didReceiveRemoteNotification not called in iOS 13.3 when app is in background

Thanks @LiqunShen-MSFT. I'm using the Firebase plugin. I couldn't get this to work and I've implemented a workaround. Instead of relying on payload being delivered while in background, I fetch data from an API when the application is brought to foreground. That works for me. I'll revisit this later on, when I'll have some time on my hands...

I had the same problem
You need to check in your Aps definition that the property "ContentAvailable = true" is set when you send a Firebase message.
This tells your app that the event is also called in the background.
var aps = new Aps()
{
    CustomData = iosNotificationDataObject,
    Sound = "default",
    ContentAvailable = true, //Tells the mobile app content is available
};

According to RemoteNotifications Programming content-available definition is

Provide this key with a value of 1 to indicate that new content is
available. Including this key and value means that when your app is
launched in the background or resumed,
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is
called.
(Newsstand apps are guaranteed to be able to receive at least one push
with this key per 24-hour window.)

Similiar: stackoverflow answer
Hope this helps :)
